# Generalization for poisson regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I will really appreciate if anyone could help me to find correct reference about the following problem.

Assume we have some observations with respect to, two variables $t$ and $p$. But we don’t have enough
data in  dimension $p$  to make good estimation of joint function $f(t,p)$. 
We put some simplifying assumption and suppose observed value is coming from poisson distribution with  expected $g(t)exp(ap+b)$, where $g(t)$ is some known exponential function which is estimated independently.
Is it possible to estimate $a$ and $b$ by poisson regression idea in MLE framework?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is a Poisson generalized linear model.

Let $Y=f(t,p)\sim$ Poisson$(g(t)e^{ap+b})$

Then, you can write $E[Y]=g(t)e^{ap+b}$. This can be written as a GLM:
$$ \log E[Y]=\log g(t)+ ap+b$$

Now, if you have some predictors $t$ and $p$ and some response observations $f(t,p)$, you can then easily estimate $a$ and $b$ using the $\mathbf{glm}$ package in R.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The main problem is that the observations for pairs $(t,p)$ is very sparse. So I think training data to fit on your suggested model is not sufficient at all. We can extend observations in dimension $t$ but we are only allowed to set value 0 as $E[Y]$. would you have any idea to fix it, if you agree with this issue?

Comment: If you don't have enough observations for $p$, I would fit the model only with observations where $t$ and $p$ are available.